# Type mismatch in a Kotlin extension function

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-methods

I have this simple Kotlin extension for Wrapper. I'm trying to create `Output<T>` (a sealed class) from `Wrapper<T>` but I'm getting a **Type Mismatch** error

Here I add all the code needed

```
sealed class Output<T> {
    data class WantedOutput<T>(val value: T): Output<T>()
    data class UnwantedOutput<T>(val error: Throwable) : Output<T>()
}

interface Data {
    val id: String
    val name: String?
    val age: Int?
}

data class ResponseData(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String?,
    override val age: Int?
) : Data

data class Wrapper<T>(val result: T)

fun <T> Wrapper<T>.convert() : Output<T> {
    return Output.WantedOutput(result)
}

interface Provider {
    fun getData(): Wrapper<ResponseData> // THIS MUST BE THE IMPLEMENTATION
}

class Test {

    // THE RETURN TYPE MUST BE THE INTERFACE
    fun test(): Output<Data> {
        val wrapper = Wrapper(ResponseData("ID", "ISAAC", 26))
        return Output.WantedOutput(wrapper.result)
    }

    fun test(provider: Provider): Output<Data> {
        return provider.getData().convert() // THIS FAILS
    }
}
```

**How can I make this extension conform with the correct type?** The problem is `Wrapper<T>` is not (exactly) the same type of `Output<T>`. The T from Output is the interface and the T from Wrapper is an implementation. Is it possible to tell the type system to accept this?

[image]

Comment: "CharacterResponse is an implementation of Character" How? Character is a final class. Did you create your own Character class and the compiler is thinking you mean java.lang.Character?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no Character is just an interface with some properties which is then implemented by CharacterResponse. Java.lang.Character has nothing to do with this though I see it could confuse someone.

Comment: Since you don't show [mcve], we can only guess, but the problem is likely with variance: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: @dyukha I've simplified quite a bit the example and added all the needed code to try it. Hope it now gives all information needed

Comment: Replace Output<T> by Output<out T>. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Comment: @JBNizet Wow, that simple!! It works. I'll definitely need to read more about variance and covariance to get why it didn't work before and why it's working now. Thanks